# Sphinx contents search results

Tags: python-sphinx

I am currently using the read the doc theme for sphinxdoc version 1.4.6. When I search contents the queries display the title and the start of restructure text files instead of the the title and start of the html page. Is there any possible way I can change that?

Comment: Related Sphinx tracker issue: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the sphinx extension "sphinxprettysearchresults" (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxprettysearchresults).

Their website says this:

> To display search results, Sphinx is fetching the source files of search hits and rendering excerpts in raw markup (Example).
>
> This extension removes the markup from these source files (during build time), so the search results look decent.

However, when I load it on my project, I get an error, which I will have to report.

Maybe it works fine in your project.

Comment: Do you still get the error? I yes, please report at https://github.com/TimKam/sphinx-pretty-searchresults/issues